# No able to connect to Linkedin Python API

Tags: python, rest, api, linkedin-api

I am following the steps to connect to Linkedin using the Python API.

I installed the package, but when I try to log in:

```
from linkedin import linkedin

API_KEY = "################"
API_SECRET = "###############"
RETURN_URL = "http://localhost:8000"
authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(API_KEY, API_SECRET, 
RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())
print authentication.authorization_url
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "C:\Users\maria\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

File "<ipython-input-11-c4a6e3368b44>", line 1, in <module>
from linkedin import linkedin

 File "C:\Users\maria\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\linkedin\linkedin.py", line 294
except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.HTTPError), error:
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas? What could it be the problem?

Comment: My guess is, the library is compatible with python 2.7 version and you are running it with python 3+

Comment: So you think if I use a virtual environment with python 2.7 that would fix the issue?

Comment: `except Exception, e` is the old syntax for `except Exception as e` and is not supported since Python 3.0.

Comment: Thank you SO VERY MUCH!!

Comment: @Mariano yes, using 2.7 should work.

Answer (score 0):

use [python3-linkedin](https://pypi.org/project/python3-linkedin/) if you're using python 3

it is the same as [ozgur python-linkedin](https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin) but for python 3

Comment: Thank you so very much for your help. Do you know how to fill in the initial details? below I have completed the part I think I know
consumer_key = ?
consumer_secret= ?
user_token= client_ID (from developer's site)
user_secret= client_secret (from developers's site)
redirect_uri= http://localhost:8080/code

Comment: I used the quick_api only. regarding your question, check the code snippet right beneath the **Production Authentication** on [python3-linkedin](https://pypi.org/project/python3-linkedin/). again, i haven't tried it but it seems helpful for you.